# Running three iterations on a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am running a listing on a page in a row with three columns each. Each column requires different classes, I need to find a way to return these classes in a foreach loop to achieve the following ...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="box_skin1">...</div>
  <div class="box_skin2">...</div>
  <div class="box_skin3">...</div>

  <div class="box_skin1">...</div>
  <div class="box_skin2">...</div>
  <div class="box_skin3">...</div>
</div>
```

I am currently using the following for alternating rows but now need to add a third ... how do I do that?

```
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($newsRecords as $record): ?>
        <?php if($counter % 2) : ?>
             <!-- ROW 1 -->
             <div class="box_skin1">...</div>
        <?php else : ?>
             <!-- ROW 2 -->  
             <div class="box_skin2">...</div>
        <?php endif; ?>       
     <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `else if` statement in between clear things up? That and using `% 3` instead of `% 2`? This way you're iterating in groups of three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

**EDITED**

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($newsRecords as $record): ?>
        <?php if($counter % 3 == 0) : ?>
             <!-- ROW 3 -->
             <div class="box_skin3">...</div>
        <?php elseif ($counter % 3 == 2) : ?>
             <!-- ROW 2 -->  
             <div class="box_skin2">...</div>
        <?php elseif  ($counter % 3 == 1): ?>
             <!-- ROW 1 -->  
             <div class="box_skin1">...</div>

        <?php endif; ?>       
     <?php $counter++; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is returning the following structure 'box_skin3', 'box_skin3', 'box_skin2', 'box_skin3', 'box_skin3', 'box_skin2'. so it does not work

Comment: That works. Perfect. Can you explain in 'English' this code `($counter % 3 == 2)`? I thought modulus only returns 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

IF-ELSE free structure. If you plan to add new div then you dont have to add new else-if condition just you need to increase counter size and it will work.

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
 <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($newsRecords as $record): ?>
       <div class="box_skin<?php echo $counter; ?>">...</div>
     <?php 
      $counter++; 
      if ($counter >= 3) {
         $counter = 1;
       }
     ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if I were alternating rows. It is return 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 but what I need is 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3

Comment: then remove = from this $counter >= 3 or increase to $counter >= 4, and upvote if it will work :)